# Changing square label into circle in chartJS

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js and ng chart2, and I want to change the square into a circle in the dataset popup; but when I try to change the `pointStyle` to a cicle, nothing happens! Its still a square! How to fix this?

[image: the bar]

```css
datasets: [
      {
        data: this.salesSum,
        maxBarThickness: 100,
        borderRadius: 150,
        pointStyle: "circle"
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could configure tooltip plugin setting `usePointStyle` option to true.

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      usePointStyle: true
    }
  }
}
```